# How to call Oracle stored procedure with custom object as input parameter

Tags: java, oracle, object, stored-procedures

In Oracle database I have defined type:

```
create or replace TYPE person_type
    AS OBJECT (id NUMBER(10), name VARCHAR2(50), age NUMBER);
```

and a stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE add_person (in_person IN person_type)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT into person (id, name, age) VALUES(in_person.id, in_person.name, person.age);
END;
```

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate and I want to call the procedure with some equivalent java bean as input parameter.
I have seen many examples but they were using only basic types, not composed objects.
There are also some examples with Table annotations, but I'm not guaranteed to have such table in database, I have only guaranteed the stored procedure type.

Comment: Read this..https://technology.amis.nl/2008/07/16/oracle-jdbc-passing-a-table-of-custom-object-type-to-a-stored-procedure-implementing-efficient-single-round-trip-data-exchange-part-two-of-an-adf-application-on-a-plsql-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`StructDescriptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/StructDescriptor.html) to get you SQL structured object, which then need to pass to [`STRUCT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html) to create type.

In `StructDescriptor`, you need to pass the SQL object name i.e. `PERSON_TYPE` and the connection object i.e. `con`.

```
StructDescriptor StructDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("PERSON_TYPE", con);
```

Then, pass the structure descriptor and object array to struct. Please, note, the array index represent its sequence/place, the way it (SQL object) was declared on SQL object. As `id` was the first, then `name` and then `age`.

```
Object[] ObjArray = new Object[3];
ObjArray[0] = 1;
ObjArray[1] = "My Name";
ObjArray[2] = 23;

STRUCT structObj = new STRUCT(StructDesc, con, ObjArray);
```

Now, using struct object, you call your procedure

```
stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{call add_person(?)}");
stmt.setSTRUCT(1, structObj);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How did you get the connection "con"? Hibernate session won't allow access to it.